# Locate Jquery Element

Tags: jquery

I want to know about jquery selector to find the parent element where children contains foo.

We can do this in xpath, but what would be the jquery way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: `$("*:contains('foo')").parent()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `has` helper to filter found set of fields by has specific child criteria

https://api.jquery.com/has/

```js
console.log($('div').has('.foo').attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="c1">
  <span class="foo"></span>
</div>

<div id="c2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find the children and go to the parent from there like so:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $parent = $(".foo").parent()
      console.log($parent.attr("id"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imTheParent">
  <span class="foo"></span>
</div>
<div id="imNotTheParent">
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```